# Stat tracking in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I’m making a Node + MongoDB app where users can save books to their ‘library’. The current working build just has one collection of users, which looks like the following:

```
users:[
{
    _id: ...,
    name: “Name”,
    … other info,
    library: [
        {
            bookName: “In Cold Blood”,
            author: “Truman Capote”
            ISBN: 123783742
            _id: ...
        }
    ]
},
... other users]
```

This works functionally for what I need. But in the long run, I may want to display some statistics that involve all users. For example, the most popular book or the most popular author, or genre.

I'm thinking I'll have to make a new collection for each of the things I want to track, and then whenever a user saves a book, check if its genre and author etc. are already in the database, if not create them, and keep a separate tally of total likes there? Would this be the correct way to handle such a thing in a noSQL database? Are there any better ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at MongoDB's [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/#return-the-five-most-common-likes). You *could* keep a collection of stats, but they might go out of sync with your actual data.

By using MongoDB's aggregation pipeline, you could easily aggregate across the data to determine which is the most popular book/author/genre:

```
db.users.aggregate(
  [
    { $unwind : "$library" },
    { $group : { _id : "$library.bookName" , number : { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $sort : { number : -1 } },
    { $limit : 5 }
  ]
)
```

If possible, try to limit the scope of the aggregation so it doesn't need to aggregate over as many users. You can do this using a `$match` stage before the `$unwind` stage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks like it might do the trick - I'll have to spend some time getting my head around how it works but I'm sure it'll be worth it in the long run. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, there is a bit of a learning curve when learning aggregations, but they're very powerful. This is totally irrelevant to the original question, but If you're interested in aggregations/stats, check out [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch).